# Find the users that have statuses (A,B) and do not have statuses (C,D) at the same time

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have 2 tables:

```
USERS(ID,NAME)
USERS_STATUSES(ID,USER_ID,STATUS)
```

and the USER may have many statuses for ex. the user x has (A,C) statuses

I need to get all the USERS the users that have  statuses (A,B) and do not have statuses (C,D) at the same time form USERS_STATUSES table

so the user in the example must not be returned.

What is the query that return this result, please?

Thanks!

Comment: Should a user that has status A but not B be included?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using `group by` and a `having` clause:

```
select user_id
from users_statuses us
group by user_id
having sum(status = 'A') > 1 and
       sum(status = 'B') > 1 and
       sum(status = 'C') = 0 and
       sum(status = 'D') = 0;
```

Your question is a little vague.  I'm not sure if you want to preclude *both* C and D at the same time, or just one of them.  So, you might want:

```
having sum(status = 'A') > 1 and
       sum(status = 'B') > 1 and
       (sum(status = 'C') = 0 or
        sum(status = 'D') = 0
       )
```

Answer (score 1):

This is MySQL specific because I'm grouping by ID and selecting all columns from users table, but it's correct on this context:

```
SELECT u.*
FROM
  users u INNER JOIN users_statuses s
  ON u.id=s.user_id
GROUP BY
  u.id
HAVING
  COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN s.status IN ('A','B') THEN s.status END)=2
  AND
  SUM(s.status IN ('C','D'))=0
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for having statuses A or B and not C and D

```
select id, name
from users 
where id in (select id from users_statuses where statuses in ('A', 'B'))
and id not in (select id from users_statuses where statuses in ('C', 'D'))
```

If you need both A and B and not C and D replace with the following

```
select id, name
from users 
where id in (select id from users_statuses where statuses = 'A')
and id in (select id from users_statuses where statuses = 'B')
and id not in (select id from users_statuses where statuses in ('C', 'D'))
```

Comment: I always recomment NOT EXISTS instead if NOT IN. (If a NULL shows up in the sub-select...)

Answer (score -1):

May be this query will help you. it works fine integer and i don't know about string

```
 select * from table_name where status in(1, 2) AND status not in(3, 4);
```